Can I do this just in Javascript?
Trying to build a string in C# to pass to Javascript
Formatter = @$"function(value, opts) {{ if (value === undefined) {{return '';}} return Intl.NumberFormat('{CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name}', {{ style: 'currency', currency: '{RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.ISOCurrencySymbol}' }} ).format(value);}}" } };

This works but pretty sure there must be a way of not needing the C# calls.
Maybe what I am really asking is there anyway in Javascript of formatting an integer into a currency value (eg. 2567 -> £2567.00) using the current Culture/Locale set in the browser. As I stated in a comment all the examples I can find for Intl.NumberFormat require you to specify what Culture/Locale/Currency to use.

What is your end goal here?

Try to make your question more specific than just "Can I do this just in Javascript?". Do what specificially? Also, you can use ` to do inline code blocks or ``` to start and end full code blocks.

Sorry if I wasn't precise enough with my question. I am using ApexCharts in Blazor WASM and tring to format the y axis Tool tip of a pie chart. "Value" is a number and it is used as a % in the data label and the sum is the tool tip. I am trying to convert the sum tool tip into a currency based on the current Culture - sorry Locale I think it is called in Javascript. To do this I am using Intl.NumberFormat but all the examples I could find had you passing in the locale and currency code. Just trying to get around using C# to get them.

As you can see I am really unfamiliar with Javascript...

Quick answer, no, there is no way to determine the users (browsers) Currency in JS. I can  use undefined instead of CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name but will have to keep using RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.ISOCurrencySymbol for the currency.
Welcome to correct me if I am wrong.
